# Twilio: Are 11200 Error's attempted more than once?

Tags: twilio

This isn't a question about why I got 11200 error. All I'm asking, is if twilio attempts the request again at a later time?

The documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200 , doesn't mention anything about reattempting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio doesn't retry any calls that fail. You would need to build it into your system so when you think something should have completed but it hasn't, you get it to trigger a Twilio request again.

Alternatively, if you have an unstable server, on your webhook, you can configure a fallback URL. You can also use that to let you know when Twilio tried to make a request and failed because your primary webhook was down.

Hope this help you